# Append series of videos together in Python/OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, video-processing

I'm processing a video file and decided to split it up into equal chunks for parallel processing with each chunk running on its own process. I generate this series of video files that I want to  connect together to make the original video.

I'm wondering what's the most efficient way of stringing these videos together without having to append frame by frame? (and ideally deleting the video files after they are read so I'm only left with one big video).

[image: List of .mov files]

Comment: Why not just merge them using something like ffmpeg from the command line. This is definitely not something you need OpenCV for.

Comment: Thanks! I found some documentation, ffmpeg seems like the tool I need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wanted a programmatic solution oppose to a command. I found moviepy very useful for concatenating videos (its based on ffmpeg). Natsort is very useful for organizing the files by numerical order.

```
from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip, concatenate_videoclips
from natsort import natsorted


#path is path to folder of videos
def concatVideos(path) :
    currentVideo = None
    #List all files in the directory and read points from text files one by one
    for filePath in natsorted(os.listdir(path)):
        if filePath.endswith(".mov"):
            if currentVideo == None:
                currentVideo = VideoFileClip(path + filePath)
                continue
            video_2 = VideoFileClip(path+filePath)
            currentVideo = concatenate_videoclips([currentVideo,video_2])

    currentVideo.write_videofile("export".mp4")
```

Comment: this library produces corrupted video files